# VBA function for excel 2010 to find number in string

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am using excel 2010 and do not have the GetNumeric function available.
I need to get the string from "A1:A200" and put just the numeric value in "B2:B200"
I have tried to use the "Sumproduct but not had much luck.
Thank you for taking the time to check out my question.

Comment: Possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868923/excel-vba-get-numeric-value-from-alphanumeric) ? ... and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Answer (score 0):

For an Excel formula you can use this:

```
=SUM(MID(0&A2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$99),1))*ROW($1:$99),),ROW($1:$99))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$99)/10)
```

I copied the formula from this [website](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3244-excel-remove-letters-from-strings-cells-numbers.html), which also provides other options for returning only a numeric value from a cell.